# Conditional type depending on a value of function arguments

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to combine 2 separate Typescript methods into one with the same name `getDevice`. First function requires just a number to return a `Device` or `null` in case there's no device:

```js
protected getDevice(deviceId: number): Device | null {
  const device = this.devicesService.getDevice(deviceId);
  if (device == null)
    console.warn(`Failed to get the device #${deviceId}.`);
  return device;
}
```

The second function takes 2 arguments. First one is either a number (like previous function) or a `Device` (result of previous function):

```js
protected getDeviceAs<T extends DeviceType>(
  deviceOrId: Device | number,
  deviceType: (new (device: Device) => T),
): T | null {
  const device = typeof deviceOrId === 'number'
    ? this.devicesService.getDevice(deviceOrId)
    : deviceOrId as Device;
  if (device == null) {
    console.warn(`Failed to get the device #${deviceOrId}.`);
    return null;
  }
  return new deviceType(device);
}
```

A result of combining two methods would be something like this:

```js
protected getDevice<T extends DeviceType>(
  deviceOrId: Device | number,
  deviceType: (new (device: Device) => T) | null = null,
): Device | T | null {
  let device: Device | null = null;
  // In case deviceOrId is a number
  if (typeof deviceOrId === 'number') {
    device = this.devicesService.getDevice(deviceOrId);
    if (device == null) {
      console.warn(`Failed to get the device #${deviceOrId}.`);
      return null;
    }
    if (deviceType == null) return device;
  }

  // getDeviceAs functionality
  return new deviceType(device);
}
```

The problem is I can't wrap my head how to properly type the whole function:

- return type depends on the `deviceOrId` argument type:

  - if `deviceOrId` is a `Device`, then for sure the result must be `T | null`
  - if `deviceOrId` is a `number`, then its could be `Device | T | null`
- return type and `deviceOrId` depend on the `deviceType` argument:

  - if `deviceType` is a `null` then the `deviceOrId` must be of type `number` and return type of `Device | null`
  - if `deviceType` is the `(new (device: Device) => T)` then the return type must be `T | null`

Is it even possible in Typescript? If yes how? Maybe with some function overloading tricks?

Comment: It's actually really easy but perhaps not obvious syntactically. You can overload the signature of method as many times as you  need to correlate any number of parameter lists to result types. When a function signature is overloaded, the implementation does not contribute to the overload set and but did not corrupt the API surface

Comment: See the typescript handbook for details https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad! I completely missed the part that the implementation does not contribute to the overload set. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy solution to the problem. You can overload functions in typescript ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)). First you declare you function signatures. In case of this question it would be:

```js
protected getDevice(deviceId: number): Device | null;
protected getDevice<T extends DeviceType>(
  deviceOrId: Device | number,
  deviceType: (new (device: Device) => T),
): T | null;
```

Then you write the function implementation that will handle the logic. That implementation function signature won't be considered as another overload. Full code:

```js
// Overload 1:
protected getDevice(deviceId: number): Device | null;
// Overload 2:
protected getDevice<T extends DeviceType>(
  deviceOrId: Device | number,
  deviceType: (new (device: Device) => T),
): T | null;
// Implementation:
protected getDevice<T extends DeviceType>(
  deviceOrId: Device | number,
  deviceType: (new (device: Device) => T) | null = null,
): Device | T | null {
  let device: Device | null = null;
  if (typeof deviceOrId === 'number') {
    device = this.devicesService.getDevice(deviceOrId);
    if (device == null) {
      console.warn(`Failed to get the device #${deviceOrId}.`);
      return null;
    }
    if (deviceType == null) return device;
  }
  return new deviceType(device);
}
```